# How to normalise complex JSON with multiple levels of nested information in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, json-normalize

I get the data in a predefined format I cannot change:

```
data = 
{
  "id": 12345,
  "name": "Doe",
  "gender": {
    "textEn": "Masculin"
  },
  "professions": [
    {
      "job_description": {
        "textEn": "Job description"
      },
      "cetTitles": [
        {
          "cetTitleType": {
            "textEn": "Recognition"
          },
          "issuanceDate": "1992-04-14T00:00:00Z",
          "phoneNumbers": [
            "123 221 00 70"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

While I can normalise data one level down ('gender') through the pd.json_normalize function, I struggle to access info further down in the hierarchy.

I tried e.g. getting the job description through
`data = pd.json_normalize(data,record_path=['professions','job_description'],meta='id')`
but I get a TypeError. How can I address this and extract all data into a table so the data above is represented as one row with all content as fields?

The output I would like to ultimately achieve looks as follows:

| id | name | gender | job_description | cetTitleType | issuanceDate | phoneNumbers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Doe | Masculin | Job description | Recognition | 1992-04-14T00:00:00Z | 123 221 00 70 |

Comment: What is the expected output for this example?

Comment: Ultimately I would like to consolidate ~10’000 of those data files into a table where each file is represented as a row. The aim is to extract all data into one row in a table (so fields for id, gender, job description, issuance date, …)

Comment: What is the expected output for *this example*?

Comment: added expected output to question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [json_normalize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

Code:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(
    data=data,
    record_path=["professions", "cetTitles"],
    meta=["id", "name", "gender", ["professions", "job_description"]]
).explode(column="phoneNumbers")

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop("gender").values.tolist()))
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(".").str[-1]
df = df.rename(columns={"textEn": "gender"})
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop("job_description").values.tolist()))
df = df.rename(columns={"textEn": "job_description"})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
           issuanceDate   phoneNumbers       gender     id name    gender  job_description
0  1992-04-14T00:00:00Z  123 221 00 70  Recognition  12345  Doe  Masculin  Job description
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution with json_normalize as per question! By now I have realised that it's potentially easier to create a df with predefined columns ( pd.DataFrame(columns=["id","..."]) ), access the json data directly (data["id"]), construct a row (row_with_new_data = [data["id"],data["..."]] and append it to the df via df.loc[len(df)] = row_with_new_data. Just putting it here as an alternative for the next guy who tries to solve this through json_normalize